# How can I avoid a NumberFormatException in Java?

Tags: java, exception, casting

i searched, i found, but it all didn't work. my problem is that the `NumberFormatException` is thrown while I want to cast from `String` to `double`.

The string array atomized contains many strings and I tried to make an output before to make them visible so I could be sure there is data. the only problem is the double value. it is something like 5837848.3748980 but the valueOf method always throws the exception here. I have no idea why.

```
try
{
 int key = Integer.valueOf(atomized[0]);

 double value = Double.valueOf(atomized[1].trim());

 int role = Integer.valueOf(atomized[2]);

 Double newAccountState = this.bankKonto.charge(key, value, role);
 System.out.println("NEW Account State "+newAccountState);
 this.answerClient(newAccountState.toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
 System.out.println(e.getClass().toString()+" "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Exception output:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "109037.0"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at vsys.ue02.server.Bank.computeData(Bank.java:122)
        at vsys.ue02.server.Bank.run(Bank.java:160)
```

Comment: darioo is basically asking for the exception log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works fine here. So I'd assume your system locale has `,` rather than `.` for decimal separator. To avoid these things you can use `DecimalFormat`:

```
new DecimalFormat().parse("5837848.3748980");
```

Judging by the name of your variable - account - I assume you are dealing with money. You must never use floating point types to represent money. Use `BigDecimal`, or possibly `int`

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/conversion/num2string.html) is a starting point for using DecimalFormat to convert strings to numbers. Also, if you are dealing with money and currencies, you should consider using [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of double.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Integer.parseInt on a number with a decimal point - that is not a valid integer - visible in your stack trace

Comment: the problem was something like that. i have here inter process communication and the atomized array contains incomming data in a form of a protocol. it wasn't parsed correctly. but now it works and with bigdecimal it works much better!